# How to make viewport backgroundcolor clear in OpenGLES 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es-2.0

I wanna make viewport backgroundcolor clear,transparent.
But

```
glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

do not work,it is just all black.

I am using OpenGLES2.0 and iOS platform。

```
glClearColor(backgroundColorRed, backgroundColorGreen, backgroundColorBlue, backgroundColorAlpha);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

So how to do it if I want to make viewport backgroundcolor transparent?

Answer (score 0):

I think the glview cannot be transparent.

Here is an example, you have a UIImageView which contain a background image.

You want to add a transparent glview upon the UIImageView, make it like watermark.

Unfortunately, the glview cannot be transparent, so the Alternative way is:
Make two gl_textures, one texture use to draw your background image. Another one draw you're watermark.

The gl_texture can be transparent.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.I found out that it is the opaque propery of CAEAGLLayer that I set wrong.Make it NO will be ok.

Comment: @Stroman I used to try the opaque propery, but it not work. Maybe I do something wrong. Thanks for respond.